# environ doesn't seem to end with NULL

Tags: c, null, segmentation-fault, environment-variables

The following code seems to end with a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". I thought environ variable was supposed to end with a NULL terminating pointer. I just want to print every environment variable, so what am I doing wrong? How do I know I've gotten to the last environment variable?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern char **environ;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    char *s = *environ;
    for(i=0; s!=NULL; i++)
    {
        printf("env%d: %s\n", i, s);
        s =  *(environ+( sizeof(char *)*i ));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, you're dereferencing the first pointer (getting the first environment variable). Change your iteration pointer to a pointer-to-a-pointer. As it stands, you are double-printing the first entry.

Also, your incrementation of the pointer is what's causing the segmentation fault. Its stride is more than one pointer width, causing you to run off the end of the array most of the time while also missing most of the entries.

```
char ** s = environ;

for( int i = 0; *s != NULL; i++ )
{
    printf( "env%d: %s\n", i, * s );
    s ++;
}
```

Comment: The `// Works on all compilers that I know of` comment doesn't seem justified; it seems to imply you're doing something nonstandard or incorrect but that happens to work everywhere. I see no such issue. The code is just correct.

Comment: I'm not sure how the old long pointers of early windows may have affected general pointer arithmetic, so I added the caveat. Removed.

Comment: Your diagnosis of the error in the code in the question isn't right. The code is simply stepping through the array with a stride of `sizeof(char*)` rather than a stride of 1.

Comment: Thank you, puzzled through it with your answer, but forgot to edit mine.

Answer (score 5):

Your use of

```
*(environ+( sizeof(char *)*i ))
```

is simply wrong. The pointer arithmetic is incorrect. The multiplication by `sizeof(char *)` is wrong. That results in taking large strides over the array and running off the end. If you wanted to use pointer arithmetic you would simply write:

```
*(environ+i)
```

But of course, at that point you have reduced this to a rather clunky way to say:

```
environ[i]
```

So, you should, in my opinion, most clearly write the loop using `environ[i]`. For instance like this:

```
int i = 0;
while(environ[i] != NULL)
{
    printf("env%d: %s\n", i, environ[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Or as a for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; environ[i] != NULL; i++)
{
    printf("env%d: %s\n", i, environ[i]);
}
```

Comment: You edited your answer, so ignore the old comment too.

Comment: @Horse I've not changed the sense of the answer. If you are using an index then `[]` seems to be a clearer way to go.

Comment: You started with suggesting changing s!=NULL to *s!='\0'. This didn't fix the issue at all.

Comment: Your now deleted comment appeared to me when my answer was in its current form, hence my confusion.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern char **environ;
//...

int i = 0;
while(environ[i]) {
  printf("%s\n", environ[i++]);
}
```

dont forget that c have pointer arithmetic so `environ+( sizeof(char *)*i )` has to be `environ + i` the compilier automaticly shift the base address by i*sizeof(char *).

Answer (score 3):

Using pointer arithmetic is a way to go, just make sure you increment correctly:

```
size_t i = 0; /* To index arrays (or just count them)  or to access memory, size_t is the 
                 preferred type, as it is guaranteed to be wide enough to access all  
                 memory. Also it does not waste any bit for unused negative numbers. */
char ** s = environ;
for(; *s != NULL; ++i)
{
    printf("env%zu: '%s'\n", i, *s);
    ++s; /* Incrementing a pointer increments so many bytes 
            as the type the pointer is pointing to uses.  */
}
```

I'd however used a `while`-loop:

```
char ** s = environ;
while (*s)
{
    printf("env%td: '%s'\n", (*s - *enviro), *s);
    ++s; 
}
```

Comment: This would only increment through the characters of the first element, showing a successively shorter substring. (I noticed you just fixed this)